# APP inside docker can only see client coming from IP 172.17.0.1 how to avoid it?

Tags: networking, dock

my app live inside the docker log all in-coming traffic from 172.17.0.1
I believe it's named dock0 bridge hub??

is it possible to avoid it? to let the app inside see ourside client real ip?

I also saw a way name network type as host but the docker container will share the same ip with host?
is that possible to do it like host is 192.168.1.101 docker container is 192.168.1.102?

Answer (score 0):

OK.. I found there is a solution, docker have something named macvlan driver.

basicly it's like the br0 for normal homerouter.
it can plug container into the REAL L2 bridge instead of the fake docker0 NAT ("bridge.")

but I can't use it, macvlan only support on linux host, but im using a mac.